# Could not connect to SMTP host. Mailer Error: SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host

Tags: php, smtp, phpmailer

I'm using `PHPMailer` for sending mail with authentication, but i'm getting the following message when i tried to run my **sendmessage.php.**

```
SMTP -> ERROR: Failed to connect to server: Connection timed out (110) 
SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host. Mailer Error: SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host.
```

can anyone please tell me why i'm getting this message...and some solution for this

Mycode is as given below

**sendmessage.php**

```
<html>
<head>
<title>PHPMailer - SMTP (Gmail) basic test</title>
</head>
<body>

<?php

//error_reporting(E_ALL);
error_reporting(E_STRICT);

date_default_timezone_set('America/Toronto');

require_once('../class.phpmailer.php');
//include("class.smtp.php"); // optional, gets called from within class.phpmailer.php if not already loaded


$mail = new PHPMailer(); // create a new object
$mail->IsSMTP(); // enable SMTP
$mail->SMTPDebug = 1; // debugging: 1 = errors and messages, 2 = messages only
$mail->SMTPAuth = true; // authentication enabled
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl'; // secure transfer enabled REQUIRED for GMail
$mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
$mail->Port = 465; // or 587
$mail->IsHTML(true);
$mail->Username = "myemailid@gmail.com";
$mail->Password = "myemailpassword";
$mail->SetFrom('myemailid@gmail.com','vgvb');
$mail->Subject = "Test";
$mail->Body = "hello";
$mail->AddAddress('myfriendemailid');
 if(!$mail->Send())
    {
    echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    }
    else
    {
    echo "Message has been sent";
    }
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Has your host enabled your server to communicate on port 465? Some hosts won't allow you to send mail from them.

Comment: do we have that by default..........how to check that

Comment: You will have to call or email your hosting provider.

Comment: @user3159579  
to check if you are allowed to communicate using that port
===============================================

'open **cmd**'  
'type **telnet smtp.gmail.com 465**'  
if you get response from the server then you are allowed to communictae

Comment: @user3159579 
to check if you are allowed to communicate using that port  


`open cmd`
`type telnet smtp.gmail.com 465`  
if you get response from the server then you are allowed to communictae

Answer (score 1):

Open ***php.ini*** file from WAMP and verify that **openssl.dll** is uncommented .

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$mail->Host = "ssl://smtp.gmail.com";
```

Comment: try to delete $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl'; aswell

Answer (score 0):

The issue might be your firewall blocking the smtp.gmail.com, instead give the IP Address it should work

```
74.125.129.108
```